# Очистка памяти

Tags: stl, память, c++

Приветствую.
Кто может объяснить суть этой ситуации и как её исправить?

Здесь я создаю простой класс с 2мя полями std::string и заполняю вектор объектами этого класса. смотрю на загруженную память, затем "пытаюсь" её очистить, но ничего не выходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    string s1;
    string s2;

    Foo( string s1, string s2 ) {   this->s1 = s1; this->s2 = s2; };

    ~Foo() { }; 
};

void printState( string msg )
{
    cout << msg << endl;
    system("ps aux | grep test");
    cin.ignore();
}

int main( void )
{
    printState( "Program has been started" );

    int const N = 100000;
    int i;

    vector < Foo * > vec;   
    for ( i=0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        string s1 = "The some string. Bla bla bla..";
        string s2 = "123456789012345678901234567890";

        Foo * tmp = new Foo( s1, s2 );
        vec.push_back( tmp );   
    }

    printState( "Load has been completed" );

    for ( i=0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        delete vec[i];
    }

    printState( "Unload has been completed" );

    return 0;
}
```

Результат

```
Program has been started
root     24601  0.0  0.0  11720  1060 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 ./test
root     24602  0.0  0.0   3956   568 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep test
root     24604  0.0  0.0   6028   680 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 grep test

Load has been completed
root     24601  2.5  0.2  28328 17488 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 ./test
root     24605  0.0  0.0   3956   568 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep test
root     24607  0.0  0.0   6028   680 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 grep test

Unload has been completed
root     24601  2.6  0.2  28328 17488 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 ./test
root     24608  0.0  0.0   3956   568 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep test
root     24610  0.0  0.0   6028   680 pts/8    S+   16:07   0:00 grep test
```

Comment: пользуйтесь `grep test | grep -v grep` :)

Answer (score 5):

Специально прогнал Ваш код под valgrind'ом. Даже увеличил `N` в 10 раз (для надежности).  Все 142777208 байт памяти были возвращены назад системе. В данном примере утечек нет.

Но есть много других возможностей, как можно растартить всю память, при этом что бы без утечек. Некоторые люди не знают, что если с вектора удалить все элементы, то он не отдает всю память назад (деструктор конечно возвратит все, но пока он не вызван - часть памяти удерживается - [можно почитать здесь](http://youdevelop.ru/stl-pro-lesson2/)).

Ещё один способ - фрагментация памяти. Если постоянно создавать мелкие объекты разного размера, то через какое то время память будет "дырявая". То есть, часть по факту, свободно 90% памяти, а в реальности - 16 байт занято, 152 свободно, и так вся память. И если захочется выделить 200 байт памяти - ничего не получится - памяти нет (цифры взяты с головы без привязки к конкретной архитектуре и компилятору).

Comment: Дело в том, что я слежу за памятью через htop (top, ps) и она там явно росла с одинаковой скоростью, как в этом примере так и там (реальном приложении). Может быть это зависит от компилятора, я компилировал с помощью g++

Comment: я также с помощью g++ компилировал.
А доверять htop (и другим подобных) нужно аккуратно и правильно интерпретировать. Запустите под valgrind и посмотрите.

Comment: Кстати. если я сделаю вызов деструктора у вектора, vec.~vector(); то в том же htop показатель памяти уменьшается. т.е. доля правды есть. Хорошо я попробую valgrind

Comment: вот такой вызов `vec.~vector();` может привести к серьезный проблемам.

Comment: Можете объяснить?

Comment: Здесь не нужно объяснять. Так как конструктор для этого объекта был вызван автоматически,то и деструктор будет вызван также (компилятор вставляет соответствующий код).

С другой стороны, если нужно вызвать деструктор, то его вызывают через free, но опять же для тех объектов, которые были созданы с помощью new.

В Вашем случае просто произойдет двойной вызов деструктора (хотя нужно смотерть в внутренности, может там ничего такого не случится).

Comment: Пнятненько. Спасибо за помощь. Буду думать.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, в этой (код в вопросе) программе проблем с памятью нет. А что Вы надеялись увидеть? 


--


Вы пишете, что течет многопоточное приложение. Это усложняет проблему. 

Могу посоветовать сначала посмотреть нет ли ошибок типа delete вместо delete[]. 

А если это не поможет, то остается только тщательно прогнать код "вручную", проанализировать все вызовы где выделяется память и убедиться, что при любом варианте завершения потока делаются вызовы, освобождающие ее.

Главное, не экспериментируйте с разными "способами" освободить память. Основной инструмент отладки - это голова.

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле, delete возвращает память в пул аллокатора. А уж когда аллокатор вернёт эту память системе, и вернёт ли вообще, зависит лишь от прихоти самого аллокатора (и от системы, на которой он бежит!).

Если вам это не нравится, вы можете написать собственный аллокатор. Это не так сложно, но вам нужно будет уметь взять память у системы и вернуть ей.

Comment: Насколько мне известно в \*nix память (выделяемую в куче) системе вернуть нельзя.

Особо переживать по этому поводу не стоит. Неиспользуемые виртуальные страницы не будут мешать остальным приложениям (и Вашему тоже).

Comment: @avp: спасибо за дополнение!

Comment: Очень интерестные подробности, но как вы понимаете этот пример основан на реальном приложении, которое сильно страдает из-за утечки памяти (многопоточный сервер) и очень часто сваливается. Я пытаюсь понять причину и наткнулся на вот эту проблему с очисткой памяти. Может есть специальные средства для поддержания памяти на нужном уровне?

Comment: @Антон: ищите проблему где-то ещё. Дело в том, что если память освободится и уйдёт аллокатору, следующее выделение получит этот самый возвращённый ранее кусок памяти, и потребление памяти больше расти не будет. То, что память растёт, означает, что какой-то код **не возвращает память аллокатору**, то есть не вызывает `delete`. Это и есть настоящая проблема.

Comment: @VladD т.е. показатель памяти при вызове ps aux показывает память, которая была использована, но не та которая сейчас в работе. Этот принцип я знаю еще из Си, если память освобождается, это не значит, что она "обнуляется" а еще некоторое время там могут хранится те же данные.

Comment: В общем, я понял что нужно копать в сторону аллокатора и смотреть что там происходит. Спасибо за советы

Comment: @Антон Лакотко: я совсем другое имел в виду: нужно копать в сторону кода, который не вызывает delete! Аллокатор скорее всего работает правильно.

Comment: @avp

> Насколько мне известно в *nix память (выделяемую в куче) системе вернуть нельзя.

Память в *nix вернуть можно. Это звисист от того где этот кусок размещается.
Выделение памяти в glibc происходит двумя способами: через brk и через mmap.
Зависит это от размера запрашиваемого куска. Мелкие выделяются в общем пространсве "arena", граница которого перемещается вызовом brk и освобождаться память может, только если освобождаемый блок оказался в конце этой области. Крупные размещаются и освобождаются индивидуально, но их размер кратен размеру страницы памяти.

см man mallinfo

Comment: @sercxjo, спасибо, я был не прав. Очень интересная информация.

Хотя в моей убунте `man mallinfo` (а также mallopt и malloc_trim) почему-то отсутствуют, я покопался в malloc.h и написал небольшую программку, которая печатает "space usage".

Возможно это поможет ТС, код в ответе.

Comment: @avp apt-get install manpages-dev

Comment: @sercxjo, вообще-то, я это делал раньше. Но, думаю, вдруг что-то изменилось...

К сожалению нет. 

    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
    ...
    manpages-dev is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ man mallinfo
    No manual entry for mallinfo
    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l

Какие есть идеи?

Comment: только в 10.10 появился эот ман

Comment: Интересно. Функции есть (и работают), а манов нет.

--

@sercxjo, кстати, как думаете (система мне регулярно предлагает обновиться на 12.04), если обновить, то Gnome (с настройками) останется или будет заменен на их дурацкую Unity?

Comment: @avp gnome там есть (в качестве основного интерфейса) и разные. Насчёт настроек -- не знаю. А man'ы -- дык эта, хрюниксы, сэр.

Comment: @avp, думаю, что будет заменен. В случае с OpenSUSE - так там точно вылез новый гномоинтерфейс.

Comment: @avp я поставил Gnome 3 из репозитория, имеет режим совместимости с 2 но много недоделок, часть настроек исчезло, часть программ неправильно взаимодействуют с треем, в системных настройках пропала куча опций. В общем всё становится похоже на тостер, переходить с Gnome 2 на Gnome 3 не советую. Может быть Gnome2 из mint попробовать.

Comment: @sercxjo, ну, мы на двух компьютерах избрали два совершенно разных варианта. Я лично откатился на кеды, хотя давно на них не сидел. И надо сказать, что я даже практически не замечаю и у них тормозов. Хотя мелкие недоработки имеются. А вот сестричка на десктопе сидит на гноме. Правда, пришлось его допилить - добавили плугинов, ес-но уже забыл каких. Но утилита пишет, что это: Panel-Docklet v14, Alternative Status Menu, Weather indicator и Panel Settings. Программы же обычно запускаем либо через док, либо через квик-ланч из доп. панели, либо из терминала, т.к. стандартным лаунчером невозможно

Comment: пользоваться. Другие же товарищи перешли на другие оконные менеджеры. Например, [LXDE][1] или [xfce][2]. Надо сказать, что у меня к ним спорное отношение, т.к. на нетбуке с этими оконными менеджерами элементы управления выползали за границу экрана. Причем безвозвратно. =(

[1]:http://ru.opensuse.org/LXDE
[2]:http://ru.opensuse.org/Xfce

Answer (score 3):

[@Антон Лакотко](/users/1472/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE), вот может быть этот тестик чем-то поможет Вам.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int
pri_mallinfo (struct mallinfo *mi)
{
  printf ("arena\t\t%d non-mmapped space allocated from system\n"
      "ordblks\t\t%d number of free chunks\n"
      "smblks\t\t%d number of fastbin blocks\n"
      "hblks\t\t%d number of mmapped regions\n"
      "hblkhd\t\t%d space in mmapped regions\n"
      "usmblks\t\t%d maximum total allocated space\n"
      "fsmblks\t\t%d space available in freed fastbin blocks\n"
      "uordblks\t%d total allocated space\n"
      "fordblks\t%d total free space\n"
      "keepcost\t%d top-most, releasable (via malloc_trim) space\n",
      mi->arena, mi->ordblks, mi->smblks, mi->hblks, mi->hblkhd,
      mi->usmblks, mi->fsmblks, mi->uordblks, mi->fordblks, mi->keepcost);
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  puts ("Hi");
  struct mallinfo mi = mallinfo();

  pri_mallinfo(&mi);
  int i, s = 0;
  char *p[1000];

  for (i = 1; i < 1001; i++) {
    p[i-1] = malloc(i*i);
    s += i*i;
  }
  printf ("\nmalloc %d times total %d bytes\n",i-1,s);
  mi = mallinfo();
  pri_mallinfo(&mi);

  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    free(p[i]);
  puts ("\nfree all");
  mi = mallinfo();
  pri_mallinfo(&mi);

  printf ("\nreturn half non-mmaped via malloc_trim(%d) to system\n", 
      mi.keepcost);
  malloc_trim(mi.keepcost/2);
  mi = mallinfo();
  pri_mallinfo(&mi);

  exit (puts("Bye") == EOF);
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc mal.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Hi
arena       0 non-mmapped space allocated from system
ordblks     1 number of free chunks
smblks      0 number of fastbin blocks
hblks       0 number of mmapped regions
hblkhd      0 space in mmapped regions
usmblks     0 maximum total allocated space
fsmblks     0 space available in freed fastbin blocks
uordblks    0 total allocated space
fordblks    0 total free space
keepcost    0 top-most, releasable (via malloc_trim) space

malloc 1000 times total 333833500 bytes
arena       16015360 non-mmapped space allocated from system
ordblks     1 number of free chunks
smblks      0 number of fastbin blocks
hblks       638 number of mmapped regions
hblkhd      319283200 space in mmapped regions
usmblks     0 maximum total allocated space
fsmblks     0 space available in freed fastbin blocks
uordblks    15884224 total allocated space
fordblks    131136 total free space
keepcost    131136 top-most, releasable (via malloc_trim) space

free all
arena       135168 non-mmapped space allocated from system
ordblks     1 number of free chunks
smblks      0 number of fastbin blocks
hblks       0 number of mmapped regions
hblkhd      0 space in mmapped regions
usmblks     0 maximum total allocated space
fsmblks     0 space available in freed fastbin blocks
uordblks    0 total allocated space
fordblks    135168 total free space
keepcost    135168 top-most, releasable (via malloc_trim) space

return half non-mmaped via malloc_trim(135168) to system
arena       69632 non-mmapped space allocated from system
ordblks     1 number of free chunks
smblks      0 number of fastbin blocks
hblks       0 number of mmapped regions
hblkhd      0 space in mmapped regions
usmblks     0 maximum total allocated space
fsmblks     0 space available in freed fastbin blocks
uordblks    0 total allocated space
fordblks    69632 total free space
keepcost    69632 top-most, releasable (via malloc_trim) space
Bye
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Признаю,  в своем комментарии (о том, что в *nix память в систему не возвращается) был неправ.
Как видно часть динамически выделенной памяти возвращается автоматически после free(), часть можно вернуть принудительно (via malloc_trim).

Comment: В данный момент я переписываю свой сервер. т.к. проверка через valgrind показала много утечек. Основной цикл уже переписан и сейчас он работает стабильно. Мне остаётся только переписать классы бизнесс логики паралельно тестируя их на текучесть. Если интерестно я могу поделится результатом работы.
Всем спасибо за советы.

Comment: делиться интересными случаями всегда нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Я переписал свой сервер с помощью valgrind'а ( Спасибо [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) )
Утечек больше не наблюдается и память всё время держится на 1м уровне.
Суть проблемы была проста, как я писал, у меня сервер многопоточный и по определённым обстоятельствам я ждал завершения потока не через wait ( pthread_join ), а через собственно объявленный флаг завершения. И всё работало отлично через этот флаг, кроме памяти, так вот оказывается, что pthread_join удаляет всё то, что было создано pthread_create
Теперь всё отлично работает.
Еще раз всем спасибо за помощь, ну а [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) отдельное!

Comment: Вам было достаточно запускать потоки в detached состоянии. Что-то такое

    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

перед

    pthread_create (&th, &attr, ...)

Comment: @Антон Лакотко: тогда вам стоило бы принять ответ @KoVadim'а.